# How to scrape data within a input tag from an iframe using R

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the data from a property portal for an academic project. The data I'm interested is Price trends and it's in a iframe. I want to get the data for upper, average and lower range. This data is stored in a input tag. I'm trying to scrape this data by referring to parent  class and then to the input tag but can't get to the data.

There are many iframes which I need to scrape but one of them is [this](https://www.99acres.com/do/pricetrends?building_id=0&loc_id=12400&prop_type=1&pref=S&bed_no=0&w=600&h=350)

The code I've tried is below but I don't get desired result.

```
#Specifying the url of the iframe to be scraped
url <- 'https://www.99acres.com/do/pricetrends?building_id=0&loc_id=12400&prop_type=1&pref=S&bed_no=0&w=600&h=350'

#Reading the HTML code from the website
download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
webpage <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")

PriceTrend_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.ptplay input')

PriceTrend_data_html
```

It would of immense help if someone can guide me here.

Comment: can't find input class anywhere

Comment: It's not a class rather a input tag where all the data I want is stored. If you search for input tag, its at the bottom of source page with id="priceTrendVariables". It has all the data which I need.

Comment: The url doesn't work (access denied).

Comment: @Alexandregeorges do you mean it just doesn't open only for you because I am still able to open it at my end? Although read_html() doesn't read it when I download the file using download.file() but it reads it very well when I copy the source code and save it as html manually. Any thoughts on this as to why this is happening? Does it have to do anything with access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it on my own after some research hence posting it here in case anyone else encounters the same issue in future. I could not read the html file using read_html() when I download the file with download.file() so had to manually download the file and then work on it.

Since the data was within input tag only so I scraped attribute with **id** of input tag and got the data I wanted. Here is the piece of code that worked for me.

```
url <- read_html("scrapedpage_chart.html")
average_prices <- html_attr(html_nodes(url, "#priceTrendVariables"), "median")
average_prices <- gsub(pattern = 'null',replacement = 'NA',x = average_prices)
average_prices <- unlist(strsplit(average,split = ","))
average_prices <- as.numeric(average)
average_prices
```